# Post content missing in view mode, but present in editor

Tags: bug, specific-question

I have a question ([How to properly implement a custom session persister in PHP + MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022416/how-to-properly-implement-a-custom-session-persister-in-php-mysql)) that for some reason doesn't show all the post contents.

In the end there is the "Added" section which contains an ordered list. Only points 1 and 2 of that list are displayed. When you edit the post, you can also see points 3 and 4. In edit mode the points 3 and 4 also appear in the preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML used to display questions and answers is cached - the post is stored in Markdown format so it would be costly to rerender the page every time it was displayed.

If there was a problem in the past then the version with the error - in this case truncated text - will be shown.

Just edit the post. This will rerender the HTML and *should* sort out the problem.

If it's still wrong, update this question.

Comment: Daniel Fischer already did that, and it got sorted out. I tried it too, but I didn't make any modifications, so I guess it ignored my "change".